# Qwt Plot not starting in origin

Tags: qt, qwt

I use a Qwtplot to plot some data. Now, the axes are from 0-50 and 0-100. Unfortunately the bottom left corner of the canvas is not exactly at (0,0) but at (-0.1,-0.1) or something close. Is there any way to put it exactly at (0,0)?

Answer (score 1):

http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot.html#acef5ea818944b93b8695d0c16924eed6

```
void QwtPlot::setAxisScale  (   int     axisId,
    double  min,
    double  max,
    double  stepSize = 0 
    )
```

Try using the above function on both axis that aren't lining up properly.  If it still has a gap of some sort, you could try setting the minimum to be just larger than zero, and see if it lines up better.

Hope that helps.